# Understanding the VaR example on wikipedia

Tags: value-at-risk

In the wikipedia page on [VaR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_at_risk)

The example says:

```
For example, if a portfolio of stocks has a one-day 5% VaR of $1 million, there is a 0.05 probability that the portfolio will fall in value by more than $1 million over a one day period if there is no trading.
```

What is the reason for the clause 'if there is no trading'?

Comment: If there is trading the portfolio caracteristics (assets risk return weights) might change therefore the VaR will change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's related to the parameters of your portfolio! Indeed, as it's a 1-Day VaR, then it tells you that you have 5% propability that your portfolio would fall under 1$M, because the market movements are random and you have 5% chances to be on the bad side of these movements. But if you make a trade (or completely liquidate your position on this portfolio) than you will change the parameters (for example : credit default probability will change if you swap a CCC bond with a AAA bond) of your portfolio!

Comment: @Richard: Thanks ;) and i appologize for those mistakes! i'm trying to improve my english :)